# Maximize the spaces

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the white spaces. I've research and finaly remove the white spaces on `.side` and `.main` but i cant remove the white space on top and below(when zoomed out).

Here's my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/4bmB6/). I appreciate any help.
[image: white]

What i want is (see image below). I'm tyring to create it like that, even when zoomed out there's no white space.

[image: output]

Comment: there are many different ways, all with trade offs: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: or `echo "css equal height columns" | google.com` for other methods.

Comment: thanks @Will I will try one of those methods sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/EH83H/

I've added a few things like

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to remove paddings and margins by default, i've added a position fixed to the container, and height: 100% to the main and left divs. Also main and left divs have a container div named bottom

Comment: Cool! But what does the position:relative in the body tag do?

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i forgot that when i was testing, you can delete that

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how about the display:block in the 'bottom' class? is there any purpose for that ?

Comment: you can delete that also, i was trying something and forgot to erase those, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The another solution is to add this to `.top` and doesn't affect the other elements (That means, other elements' padding and margin will keep the same):

```
margin:0px;
display:inline-block;
```

Please notice that only add it to `.top`. Do not do this:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Because it will also affect other elements.